# Beautiful Soup Giving Null even though the html tag is present in the Web Page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrap the reviews form this webpage
Link: https://zerotomastery.io/courses/coding-bootcamp/

[image: Reviews]

but when i access the html element using beautiful soup it gives null even thought the element is present in the webpage .

[image]

**Here is my Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
import json
from itertools import takewhile, chain
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
res = requests.get("https://zerotomastery.io/courses/coding-bootcamp/")
if (res.status_code == 200):
    page = BeautifulSoup(res.text , "html.parser")
    data = page.find("div",{"class":"divcomponent__Div-sc-hnfdyq-0 base-cardstyles__BaseCard-sc-1eokxla-0 course-testimonialstyles__TestimonialCard-sc-1v841y9-0  dRXcRh glDEeg"}    )
    print(data)
```

**Please Help Me To Solve This Issue**

Comment: that page is 404

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://zerotomastery.io/courses/coding-bootcamp/"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for testimonial in soup.select("[class*=TestimonialStatement]"):
    print(testimonial.get_text(strip=True))
    print()
```

Prints:

```
You're not just getting a coding bootcamp course here. You're getting a great educational experience and also becoming a part of a wonderful community which pushes your education and career even further.

This course was absolutely amazing! Andrei helped me learn the concepts of web development and new libraries by working on actual projects. I am so much more confident in my skills and career now, thanks Andrei!

This course is well structured and is updated timely. Andrei is truly passionate about web development and explains everything clearly. I would recommend this course to anyone who wants to know web dev in and out and expand their coding skills.

This course is so valuable. I feel that the knowledge I have attained from this course is worth more than my 2 degrees combined. It is complete and always being updated to the latest trends of the industry. This was the best investment I ever made.

All the course information is perfectly structured and explained in clear and simple terms. Tons of useful references, great support, and timely corrections and updates. Really easy to follow the instructions for all platforms. Definitely recommend it!

I can't rave enough about this course. I went into it with a basic knowledge of HTML, CSS and JavaScript. But Andrei taught me how to be a Full Stack Developer, with a thorough knowledge of coding, problem-solving and logical thinking.
```

Comment: i already scraped this page ... but the issue is comming in https://zerotomastery.io/testimonials/
page  , please tell me what is the issue